# give the most compact theta notation for the number of times the statement x=x+1 is executed in the following pseudo-code

Tags: discrete-mathematics

i need to find the most compact theta notation for this for loop. my guess is that it is n^3 but i cannot prove it.

```
for i=1 to i=n{

   for j = 1 to j= 2n+1{

       x=x+1
     }
}
```

Comment: Assume that the initial value of x is zero.  What is the final value of x?  That is the number of ties it is incremented.

Answer (score 1):

Your guess is incorrect.
This statement is executed exactly $n \cdot (2n+1)$ times.
So it's $2n^2 + n \in \Theta(n^2)$
Now just use the definition of $\Theta$ to prove it
(the proof will be a direct application of the definition of $\Theta$, so it's  nothing complicated).

Comment: I think you mean your guess is **in**correct... :)

Comment: No, it's $2n^3 + n \in \Theta (n^3)$. It is correct.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/471199/what-is-the-difference-between-%CE%98n-and-on

Comment: Ahem, $2n^2 + n$.  It is incorrect.

Comment: @peter.petrov did you just make a mathematical error since you said n*(2n+1) but wrote that it equaled 2n^3 + n instead of 2n^2+n?

Comment: @ErickWong Oh... of course.

Comment: @pnarup Yes :) Not sure how I made this mistake, due to the late hour last night probably.